# Showing All Messages https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard has no Package.swift manifest

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode12を使って
swift package manager で
https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard
をインストールしようとすると

```
Showing All Messages https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard has no Package.swift manifest
```

というエラーがでます。

質問

- Package.swift とはなんですか？（ざっくりした回答でよいです）
- こちら側でなにかできることはあるのでしょうか？（勘ですがプルリクエストを送らないと無理そうな気もしますが）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Package.swift" で検索すると以下のページがヒットしました。

[Swift.org - Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/)

(強調は引用者によるものです)

> Packages
>
> A package consists of Swift source files and a manifest file. The manifest file, **called Package.swift**, defines the package’s name and its contents using the PackageDescription module.

また、該当リポジトリの Issue では既にリクエストがされているように見えます。

[Add Swift Package Manager Support #147](https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard/issues/147)

> Why no package manager support?

1年以上更新が無いようなので、Issue や Pull Request が受け入れられるかは不透明です。
もしかしたら [フォークしたリポジトリ](https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard/network) の中に "Package.swift" を追加したものがある (かも) しれません。